# def functions repeat themselves twice per (while) loop, even though I only called them once each

Tags: python

I am making a game for a school project, where there are two players, rolling 2 dice each, and the scores are counted after each round. I made functions for the dice rolling for each player, but when I call this in the while loop (which runs 5 times for 5 rounds), it loops 5 times, but each time, it repeats the functions twice for some reason. I read it over thoroughly, but I couldn't find where i went wrong. I think it might have something to do with the if elif elif statments in the functions but I am not sure and don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate any help very much as I need to finish this and hand it in. Thanks in advance.

```
import random
#Function for Player ones rolls
def rollP1():
    #Player 1 rolls twice
    print("\n\nPlayer 1's rolls:")
    rollOne1 = random.randint(1,6)
    rollTwo1 = random.randint(1,6)
    #Checking if player 1 has a double, even total, or odd total
    #if player has a double, player gets a bonus roll
    if rollOne1 == rollTwo1:
        print("You got a double. ", rollOne1, "and ", rollTwo1,", have a 
        bonus 
        roll!")
        rollThree1 = random.randint(1,6)
        print(rollThree1)
        rollTotal1 = rollOne1 + rollTwo1 + rollThree1
        print("Your total score for this round is ", rollTotal1, ". Well 
        Done.")
    #if player gets an even total, score increases by 10
    elif (rollOne1 + rollTwo1)%2 == 0:
        rollTotal1 = rollOne1 + rollTwo1 + 10
        print("You got ", rollOne1, " and ", rollTwo1, ", your total is an 
        even number, plus 10 points. Your total for this round is now ", 
        rollTotal1, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an odd total, score decreases by 5
    elif (rollOne1 + rollTwo1)%2 != 0:
        rollTotal1 = (rollOne1 + rollTwo1) - 5
        print("You got ", rollOne1, " and ", rollTwo1, ". Unlucky, your 
        total is an odd number. Minus 5 points Your total for this round is 
        now ", rollTotal1, ". Better luck next time.")
    #Returning the total score for Player one for the round.
    return rollTotal1


#Function for Player twos' rolls
def rollP2():
    #Player 2 rolls twice
    print("\nPlayer 2's rolls:")
    rollOne2 = random.randint(1,6)
    rollTwo2 = random.randint(1,6)
    #Checking if player 2 has a double, even total, or odd total
    #if player has a double, player gets a bonus roll
    if rollOne2 == rollTwo2:
        print("You got a double. ", rollOne2," and", rollTwo2, ", have a 
        bonus roll!")
        rollThree2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print(rollThree2)
        rollTotal2 = rollOne2 + rollTwo2 + rollThree2
        print("Your total score for this round is ", rollTotal2, ". Well 
        Done.")
    #if player gets an even total, score increases by 10
    elif (rollOne2 + rollTwo2)%2 == 0:
        rollTotal2 = rollOne2 + rollTwo2 + 10
        print("You got ", rollOne2, " and ", rollTwo2, ". Your total is an 
        even number, plus 10 points. Your total for this round is now ", 
        rollTotal2, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an odd total, score decreases by 5
    elif (rollOne2 + rollTwo2)%2 != 0:
        rollTotal2 = (rollOne2 + rollTwo2) - 5
        print("You got ", rollOne2, " and ", rollTwo2, ". Unlucky, your 
        total is an odd number. Minus 5 points Your total for this round is 
        now ", rollTotal2, ". Better luck next time")
    #Returning the total score for Player two for the round.
    return rollTotal2


Total1 = 0
Total2 = 0
rounds = 1

while rounds < 6:
    print("Round ", rounds)
    rollP1()
    rollP2()
    rollTotal1 = rollP1()
    rollTotal2 = rollP2()
    print("Player 1's score for this round is ", rollTotal1, " and player 
    2's score for this round is ", rollTotal2)
    Total1 = Total1 + rollTotal1
    Total2 = Total2 + rollTotal2
    print("Player 1's total so far is ", Total1, ", Player 2's total so far 
    is ", rollTotal2, ". Round Over\n\n")
    rounds = rounds + 1
```

Comment: No, you called them twice; once in lines 2 and 3 of your while loop and then again in lines 4 and 5.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Also see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this. just took off the second calling.

```
import random
#Function for Player ones rolls
def rollP1():
    #Player 1 rolls twice
    print("\n\nPlayer 1's rolls:")
    rollOne1 = random.randint(1,6)
    rollTwo1 = random.randint(1,6)
    #Checking if player 1 has a double, even total, or odd total
    #if player has a double, player gets a bonus roll
    if rollOne1 == rollTwo1:
        print("You got a double. ", rollOne1, "and ", rollTwo1,", have a bonus roll!")
        rollThree1 = random.randint(1,6)
        print(rollThree1)
        rollTotal1 = rollOne1 + rollTwo1 + rollThree1
        print("Your total score for this round is ", rollTotal1, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an even total, score increases by 10
    elif (rollOne1 + rollTwo1)%2 == 0:
        rollTotal1 = rollOne1 + rollTwo1 + 10
        print("You got ", rollOne1, " and ", rollTwo1, ", your total is an even number, plus 10 points. Your total for this round is now ", rollTotal1, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an odd total, score decreases by 5
    elif (rollOne1 + rollTwo1)%2 != 0:
        rollTotal1 = (rollOne1 + rollTwo1) - 5
        print("You got ", rollOne1, " and ", rollTwo1, ". Unlucky,  total is an odd number. Minus 5 points Your total for this round now ", rollTotal1, ". Better luck next time.")
    #Returning the total score for Player one for the round.
    return rollTotal1


#Function for Player twos' rolls
def rollP2():
    #Player 2 rolls twice
    print("\nPlayer 2's rolls:")
    rollOne2 = random.randint(1,6)
    rollTwo2 = random.randint(1,6)
    #Checking if player 2 has a double, even total, or odd total
    #if player has a double, player gets a bonus roll
    if rollOne2 == rollTwo2:
        print("You got a double. ", rollOne2," and", rollTwo2, ", have a bonus roll!")
        rollThree2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print(rollThree2)
        rollTotal2 = rollOne2 + rollTwo2 + rollThree2
        print("Your total score for this round is ", rollTotal2, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an even total, score increases by 10
    elif (rollOne2 + rollTwo2)%2 == 0:
        rollTotal2 = rollOne2 + rollTwo2 + 10
        print("You got ", rollOne2, " and ", rollTwo2, ". Your total is an even number, plus 10 points. Your total for this round is now ", rollTotal2, ". Well Done.")
    #if player gets an odd total, score decreases by 5
    elif (rollOne2 + rollTwo2)%2 != 0:
        rollTotal2 = (rollOne2 + rollTwo2) - 5
        print("You got ", rollOne2, " and ", rollTwo2, ". Unlucky, your total is an odd number. Minus 5 points Your total for this round is now ", rollTotal2, ". Better luck next time")
    #Returning the total score for Player two for the round.
    return rollTotal2


Total1 = 0
Total2 = 0
rounds = 1

while rounds < 6:
    print("Round ", rounds)
    rolledP1 = rollP1()
    rolledP2 = rollP2()
    rollTotal1 = rolledP1
    rollTotal2 = rolledP1
    print("Player 1's score for this round is ", rollTotal1, " and player 2's score for this round is ", rollTotal2)
    Total1 = Total1 + rollTotal1
    Total2 = Total2 + rollTotal2
    print("Player 1's total so far is ", Total1, ", Player 2's total so far is ", rollTotal2, ". Round Over\n\n")
    rounds = rounds + 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really saved me. I didn' know it would call the whoe function, just needed the total value to be returned form the fuction. Really appreciate it :)